# EC2 pip Installs Not Registered When Executing Script With AWS Systems Manager

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pip, aws-ssm

I was wondering why there is a discrepancy on where a script held on ec2 is executed and the pip installs are not registering. In my situation, I created an ec2, ssh connected, pip installed all my necessary packages, created a python script, and executed it without any errors. Now I need to execute this script from a lambda function so I am trying to do so by using the AWS systems manager. To test, I used the `Run Command` option in AWS:

1. Selected AWS-RunShellScript
2. Command: `python <path_to_script>/test.py`
3. Chose my specific instance as the target
4. Ran

But when I do I get the following error:

```
import geopandas as gpd
ImportError: No module named geopandas
```

Why do the pip installed python packages not register when using the AWS Systems Manager, but the script executes just fine when I ssh into the ec2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, AWS-RunShellScript does not use Lambda function. To use Lambda, you would need to create an automation document with aws:executeScript plugin.

Using AWS-RunShellScript (Run Command), The script content is passed to ssm agent on the instance and stored as _script.sh file and executed directly using sudo privileges.

I tried the same steps mentioned and it worked okay with me on my Linux machine.

What is the operating system? Was module installed with --user option?

Maybe create a file with "pip list" and execute using python  to see the list of packages includes geopandas or not.